# .NET WinForms Control class

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls

Do all the windows and controls (including active-x) displayed inside WinForms application are derived from  System.Windows.Forms.Control class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically yes.

However, non-visual components such as Timers are derived from Component (or implement IComponent).  Only visual elements like Button and Form are derived from Control.

In addition, ActiveX controls don't derive from Control per se, because they're COM components; instead, when you import an ActiveX control, Visual Studio generates a wrapper that derives from AxHost and hosts the COM object.  (AxHost itself does derive from Control.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look at

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa651811(VS.71).aspx

> Inheritance Hierarchy
>
> System..::.Object
>
> System..::.MarshalByRefObject
>
> ```
> System.ComponentModel..::.Component
>
>  System.Windows.Forms..::.Control
>
>    System.Windows.Forms..::.AxHost
>
>    System.Windows.Forms..::.ButtonBase
>
>    System.Windows.Forms..::.DataGrid
>
>    System.Windows.Forms..::.DataGridView
>
>    System.Windows.Forms..::.DateTimePicker
>
>    System.Windows.Forms..::.GroupBox
>
>    System.Windows.Forms.Integration..::.ElementHost
>
>    System.Windows.Forms..::.Label
>
>    System.Windows.Forms..::.ListControl
>
>    System.Windows.Forms..::.ListView
>
>    System.Windows.Forms..::.MdiClient
>
>    System.Windows.Forms..::.MonthCalendar
>
>    System.Windows.Forms..::.PictureBox
>
>    System.Windows.Forms..::.PrintPreviewControl
>
>    System.Windows.Forms..::.ProgressBar
>
>    System.Windows.Forms..::.ScrollableControl
>
>    System.Windows.Forms..::.ScrollBar
>
>    System.Windows.Forms..::.Splitter
>
>    System.Windows.Forms..::.StatusBar
>
>    System.Windows.Forms..::.TabControl
>
>    System.Windows.Forms..::.TextBoxBase
>
>    System.Windows.Forms..::.ToolBar
>
>    System.Windows.Forms..::.TrackBar
>
>    System.Windows.Forms..::.TreeView
>
>    System.Windows.Forms..::.WebBrowserBase
> ```